# std::fstream::tellg() outputs file cursor pointer incorrectly?

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a `std::fstream`, which I imported using

```
std::fstream myFile { "C:/path/to/file.txt" };
```

When I want to read the first byte, I use

```
char c;
cout << myFile.tellg() << endl; // Correctly outputs 0 (begining of file)
myFile.read(&c, 1);
cout << myFile.tellg() << endl; // Should output 1, but it outputs
                                // FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA
myFile.read(&c, 1);
cout << myFile.tellg() << endl; // Should output 2, but it outputs
                                // FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFB
```

What's happening here?

I tried putting

```
midi_file.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
```

or

```
midi_file.seekg(0, myFile.beg);
```

But the cursor moves to `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA` whenever I try to read a byte.

**EDIT:**

I don't know if it has something to do, but I did an endianness test and these are the results:

```
bool endianness = *reinterpret_cast<short*>("10") & 1; // Outputs 1
```

**EDIT 2:**

The file is broken, as the output is not the same with another file, but why is it?

Here is the byte data from the file, taken from HxD, which is a `.midi` file:

```
4D 54 68 64 00 00 00 06 00 01 00 03 00 04 4D 54
72 6B 00 00 00 A1 00 C0 69 00 90 3C 5A 01 41 5A
01 45 5A 01 48 5A 01 49 5A 01 48 5A 01 45 5A 01
41 5A 01 3C 5A 01 37 5A 01 33 5A 01 30 5A 01 30 
5A 01 30 5A 01 33 5A 01 37 5A 01 3C 5A 01 41 5A 
01 45 5A 01 48 5A 01 49 5A 01 48 5A 01 45 5A 01 
41 5A 01 3C 5A 01 37 5A 01 33 5A 01 30 5A 01 30 
5A 01 30 5A 01 33 5A 01 37 5A 01 3C 5A 01 41 5A 
01 45 5A 01 48 5A 01 49 5A 01 48 5A 01 45 5A 01 
41 5A 01 3C 5A 01 37 5A 01 33 5A 01 30 5A 01 30 
5A 01 30 5A 01 33 5A 01 37 5A 01 3C 5A 01 41 5A 
01 45 00 00 FF 2F 00 4D 54 72 6B 00 00 00 41 00 
C1 72 05 91 3C 5A 00 40 5A 00 43 5A 00 48 5A 0A 
35 5A 00 41 5A 00 44 5A 00 49 5A 0A 37 5A 00 40 
5A 00 43 5A 00 48 5A 0A 41 5A 00 47 5A 0A 30 5A 
00 40 5A 00 43 5A 00 48 5A 05 32 00 00 FF 2F 00 
4D 54 72 6B 00 00 00 26 00 C2 47 0A 92 50 64 01 
52 64 09 50 78 00 52 78 0A 50 00 01 52 00 09 50 
78 01 50 00 0A 52 00 00 50 00 00 FF 2F 00
```

**EDIT 3:**

Here is the full code of this test:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::uppercase;

    fstream midi_file{ "D:/Descargas/OutFile.midi" };

    cout << midi_file.good() << endl; // Outputs 1

    char c;
    cout << midi_file.tellg() << endl; // Correctly outputs 0 (begining of file)
    midi_file.read(&c, 1);
    cout << midi_file.tellg() << endl; // Erroneously outputs FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA
    midi_file.read(&c, 1);
    cout << midi_file.tellg() << endl; // Erroneously outputs FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFB

    // Endianness test:
    cout << (*reinterpret_cast<short*>("10") & 1) << endl; // Outputs 1

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `myFile` in good state both before and after the read?

Comment: @Angew Hmm, `myFile.badbit` returns `4` and `myFile.failbit` returns `2`. But both `myFile.bad()` and `myFile.fail()` returns `0`.

Comment: I assume that curly braces `{}` when constructiing `std::fstream` is a typo? Should be `()`. Does it even compile with `{}`?

Comment: @Garmekain don't check `badbit`, that is a constant. Check `myFile.good()`.

Comment: @BenSteffan`myFile.good()` returns `1`, and there is no typo there, that type of constructor with curly braces is from c++11 (I think).

Comment: @freakish No, it's not a typo, it's just good practice (and been such since C++11).

Comment: @Garmekain Fair enough. Then I guess the file is broken. Whatever it is I could not reproduce it.

Comment: @Garmekain Not to mention that `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA` output is strange on its own. Why isn't it printing it as an int `-5`?

Comment: This has the aura of undefined behaviour and needs a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @freakish No, that's because I inserted `std::hex` and `std::uppercase` in `cout`.

Comment: @Garmekain OK, but if you post entire code **exactly** how it happens it may give us additional info on what's happening here. Also I've tried the code with the content you've provided and it works fine. It is unlikely that the failure has anything to do with the content, more likely with the underlying os/fs or perhaps the drive itself. That seems to be broken.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/fpos

Comment: I just realized that you are on Windows and not using `std::ios::binary` in the open flags. So your MIDI file will be corrupt whenever it has a return or newline control code.

Comment: @ZanLynx Oh, man, thanks! This works when using the flags `ios::in | ios::binary`. One of the first things I tried was putting `ios::binary` flag alone, with no luck. You should post this as an answer, or edit yours and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File open mode must be in `ios::binary` mode not to catch special characters.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `tellg` is **NOT** a number. It is a `pos_type`, which has some rules it needs to follow but being understandable when printed isn't one of them. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/fpos

It's primary purpose is to allow a seek operation to return to a saved position.

Also, your "endianness test" is very, very messed up. Reinterpreting a character string as a short? C doesn't work that way. **Maybe** if you had used `"\x01\x00"`

Comment: a character string it's just a `const char*`, and because the char string is 2 bytes long, it can be perfectly casted into a 2 byte variable, in this example, a `short`. I know `'0'` is `48` in decimal so the `& 1` part tells if that character's number is odd. `'0'` is not and `'1'` is, so if the `'0'` is the MSB, then `(0x100 * 48 + 49) & 1` will return true, but if `'1'` is the MSB, then `(0x100 * 49 + 48) & 1` will return false.

Comment: @Garmekain: If you like doing that I guess. But it makes you LOOK like a, um, *ignorant person* who got lucky.

Comment: @Garmekain "it can be perfectly casted" no it cannot. It shouldn't even compile because you can't cast away `const` with `reinterpret_cast`, and when your compiler gives you some slack and allows it to compile, it can crash at run time because of bad alignment, or the compiler can throw away your entire program because it exhibits UB and replace it with a NOP.

Comment: @ZanLynx `cout << fpos<int>(midi_file.tellg());` gives me same results as `cout << midi_file.tellg();`, with that ugly `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA`.

Comment: @Garmekain: The leading F's in the hexadecimal print is because it is a negative integer. The reason it is negative is none of your business, being internal to the `fpos` / `pos_type` representation. It might be the multi-byte character shift state, for example.